# Ensuring All Website Files Properly Upload With Dreamweaver

Tags: html, css, ftp, webserver, dreamweaver

I have been working on a website, viewing it locally on my computer. However, when I upload it to my server, it does not look good at all, as though it is missing files. Is there a way to check to make sure 1) everything uploaded 2) that any files referenced are indeed there and 3) that no files are referenced locally (all files are referenced relative to the site?

Answer (score 0):

In Dreamweaver, you can upload the root folder which will upload everything within it. This is at least true with the latest Creative Cloud version which you can connect directly to your server.

Also if you use Chrome you can right-click, Inspect Element to view the code. You can see if there are any files missing.

Comment: I have tons of attached files. Is there some sort of url checker that I could use. What's worrying me is I think I uploaded everything and its still not working.

Comment: Can you give me the link to the page?

Comment: Ok it looks like this file: /assets/jquery.ui.dialog.js is missing.

Comment: it's honestly looking like a complete mess